# How is this showed up?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I want to make a similar UI like that 
[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBOD8.jpg) and you can see when i clicked on an image constraint the attribute inspector shows up one more menu "Adaptive Layout Constraint" [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lwtw.jpg).
How is this happened and how i can show up the same menu in my project. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like a custom class with @IBInspectable property setAdaptiveLayout

```
class AdaptiveLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {
    @IBInspectable
    var setAdaptiveLayout: Bool {
        set {
            //doWhatYouWant
        }
        get {
            //doWhatYouWant
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer i'll check that out.